# Bootstrap ASP.Net - cannot get form controls in one row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

Please see code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eSearch" Width="75%" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
              <span>
                  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bSearch" CssClass="btn btn- success" Text="Search" OnClick="bSearch_Click" />
                  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bClear" Text="Clear" OnClick="bClear_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
                  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bAdd" Text="Add" OnClick="bAdd_Click1" CssClass="btn btn-success" /><br />
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would really, really like the search input box to occupy about 75% of the screen followed by three/four buttons - but I have tried every combination that I could think of.  But the input box does not occupy anything beyond three odd columns and the buttons all wrap around to the next row.

What am I missing here?

Many, many thanks

Iyer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the `<asp:TextBox>` to be about 75% you can use Bootstrap's grid system and use the `col-xs-9` class to wrap the `<asp:TextBox>` and the `col-xs-3` class for the buttons.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eSearch" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bSearch" CssClass="btn btn- success" Text="Search" OnClick="bSearch_Click" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bClear" Text="Clear" OnClick="bClear_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bAdd" Text="Add" OnClick="bAdd_Click1" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @tasos_k : I am afraid that does not work

The column with the <asp:TextBox> is stuck at what looks like a width of col-xs-4.

With a lot of white space between the input box and the three buttons - enough space for two columns, I think

Many thanks for helping

Comment: The screenshot is clear, you are right. I believe then that the above markup is inside a parent element that has a small width. It could be either a `col-*` class or any element with its width set

Comment: Thanks @tasos_k.  No, the col-* is directly under     
`<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eSearch" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>`

There is another row after this with col-xs-12 with an <asp:GridView that occupies the whole width of the screen.  That is all.  No other rows or columns on the page.  How can I share the the whole aspx here?

Thanks a lot - most kind of you to help

Comment: You can edit your question and paste your code, or put the code on pastebin if it easier for you